# Does Survey123 support editing existing surveys from other users via the Mobile App?

Tags: arcgis-online, feature-service, arcgis-survey123

I need to choose between ArcGIS Collector and Survey 123 for field data collection.

The workflow consists of 2 teams which both need to collect data on a single point:

**Team A:**
 1. Acquires initial point.
 2. Takes some photos, notes, and initial data.
 3. Submits/Saves

**Team B:**
 1. Edits initial point
 2. Takes more photos, more notes.
 3. Submits/Saves and closes out the position.

I've reviewed the following links, but didn't see an answer to my question. I am thinking this workflow isn't supported, but I wanted to make sure I wasn't missing something.

https://doc.arcgis.com/en/survey123/reference/formappcomparision.htm

https://doc.arcgis.com/en/survey123/browser/get-answers/faqgetanswers.htm

https://doc.arcgis.com/en/survey123/desktop/create-surveys/faqcreatesurveys.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using Collector for this workflow and style the features so you know which ones are initial collection and which ones have been reviewed using a coded domain. You could even setup a combo of workforce+collector depending on how you wanted to manage this project. With Survey123 you can edit exisiting data but not sure if this fits into your workflow like Collector would. https://doc.arcgis.com/en/survey123/desktop/create-surveys/prepareforediting.htm

Comment: I've been looking at Survey 123 recently and I too could not find a way to share data collected by different users in Survey 123. It seems only capable of creating data and pushing out to ArcGIS Online, there seems to be no mechanism for drawing data down to the mobile app. Collector has that two-way workflow. Happy to be proven incorrect!

Comment: I went with Collector. I also think the Team B workflow is map-centric since they have to find the locations that Team A setup.

Comment: For that you can setup feature search for that layer which can make it easier for the Team B users to locate the features